Stochastic Harmonic Functions
I'm currently writing and trying to program about shfs and shms and cant get any results.
Trying to repruduce with psds some stochastic harmonic functions (SHFs) /methods (SHMs)
The psd is clear, just a function about earthquakes.
SHM is also clear but the function in pic 1:pic1 gives me problems.
What is N?
Is N the sum of t const. and omega_i itterating between all the steps before?
like list1[i] = "function1" + list1[i-1] ?

the second thing:
SHF shf formula
omega_dash is differently described as omega omega_dash
and i'm not sure if the difference is ment or not.

I already got the psd, looking like that:
psd
saved in a list.
My shm looks in code like this:
def SHM(psd,t, ele):
    i = 1
    y = [0]
    phi = random.uniform(0, 2 * 3.14)
    while i != ele:
        y.append((A(i, psd) * math.cos(i*t+phi)) + y[i-1)
        i = i+1
    return y

with A beeing:
def A(i, S_0):
    dw = 1
    s = (2*(S_0[i]*dw)**0.5)
    return s

and my inputs are:
while z != 5000:
    while i != 80:
        psd.append(RuPe(S0,omega,omega*0.1,i,daem,daem))
        i = i+1
    #plt.plot(SHF(psd,80,10))
    z = z+1

RuPe is the PSD Formula
with z,i starting as 0
SHM Results
and i have no idea how to get SHF to work, so i got results like this:
def SHF(psd, t, ele):
    i = 1
    y = [0,]
    phi = random.uniform(0, 2 * 3.14)
    while i != ele:
        if i == 0:
            a = A(i,psd)
        else:
            a = abs(A(i,psd) - A(i-1,psd))
        y.append(a * math.cos((i) * t + phi))  #'''y[i-1])'''
        i = i + 1

    return y

SHF results
maybe there is another guy with experience in stochastics and could help me :/
PSD Code:
def RuPe(S_0,w_0,w_1,w,dam,dam_1):
   o1 = (1 + 4*(dam)**2*(w/w_0)**2)
   u1 = (1-(w/w_0)**2)**2 + 4*dam**2*(w/w_0)**2
   o2 = (w/w_1)**4
   u2 = (1-(w/w_1)**2)**2 + 4*dam_1**2 * (w/w_1)**2
   s = ((o1*o2)/(u1*u2))*S_0
return s

with
omega = 15.71
daem = 0.7
S0 = 10


Its about earthquakes with the variables:
omega = 15.71
daem = 0.7
S0 = 10
with the formular:
def RuPe(S_0,w_0,w_1,w,dam,dam_1):
o1 = (1 + 4*(dam)*2(w/w_0)**2)
u1 = (1-(w/w_0)*2)2 + 4*dam2(w/w_0)**2
o2 = (w/w_1)**4
u2 = (1-(w/w_1)**2)2 + 4*dam_12 * (w/w_1)**2
s = ((o1o2)/(u1u2))*S_0
So if i understand that right, my N is right what i did. But i dont understand the part of sum of modal contributions

i need both of them :/


N is just the number of sinusoidal modes (j goes from 0 to N-1). The output y should be a sum of modal contributions, not a list of them. You never state what your energy spectrum S0 is. Why don’t you concentrate on a single formulation? At present you are mixing a whole load of them up.

could you explain what "sum of modal contributions" means?
I'm not sure what that is.

It’s exactly what you have in your first two figures of equations: the big capital Sigma means a sum!
